# Background task in iOS: for using thermodo

Tags: ios

#### I want to create a background task in iOS. Specifically to collect room temperature using thermodo and send that information to a server. Guidance please.

For more information about thermodo. You can check.
http://thermodo.com/
Its a simple device which gives API's to collect room temperature and has some delegate methods to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add "App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay" to "Required background modes" in info.plist.

[image]